# Add actionbar toggle button next to the setting menu in the actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have `map` activity and I am trying to add `toggle button` to the actionbar next to the setting menu which contains the map type but I am facing a problem: the toggle button is being added to the setting items menu and not directly to the `actionbar`.

How can I add this toggle button to the actionbar next to the setting menu?

**map_menu.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Normal"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeSatellite"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Satellitte"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeTerrain"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Terrain"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeHybrid"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Hybrid"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeNone"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="None"/>

<item android:id="@+id/menu_toggle"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" 
android:icon="@drawable/off"
android:title="Share"
 />
```

**map activity:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    System.out.println("ABC MAP onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mapTypeNone:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        break;

    case R.id.mapTypeNormal:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        break;

    case R.id.mapTypeSatellite:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        break;

    case R.id.mapTypeTerrain:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        break;
    case R.id.mapTypeHybrid:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_toggle:

        if (birthSort) {
            // change your view and sort it by Alphabet
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);
            item.setTitle("On");
            birthSort = false;
        } else {
            // change your view and sort it by Date of Birth
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);
            item.setTitle("Off");
            birthSort = true;
        }


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Normal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeSatellite"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Satellitte"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeTerrain"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Terrain"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeHybrid"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Hybrid"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNone"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="None"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_toggle"
        android:icon="@drawable/off"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `AppCompat` library, the `showAsAction` from `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` doesn't work for some reason, you'll have to use one that comes from `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`.

---

You'll can add the required schema with the namespace `app` as shown below:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And then for menu items that you want to keep visible on the `ActionBar`, you can add the following attribute:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

and for the others you can add:

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

---

So your map_menu.xml would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Normal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeSatellite"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Satellitte"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeTerrain"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Terrain"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeHybrid"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Hybrid"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapTypeNone"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="None"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_toggle"
        android:icon="@drawable/off"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: it looks better but the `android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"` is being shown next to the setting items of the map types  but it must not shown there.

Comment: Ok it works now I must add `never` instead off `ifRoom` and I added to  the second `app` instead od `android`

Comment: Pleace chage `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to app:showAsAction="never" then I will accept your answer.

Comment: You can change the sequence of the menu items as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it's working for me

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeNormal"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Normal"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeSatellite"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Satellitte"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeTerrain"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Terrain"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeHybrid"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Hybrid"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapTypeNone"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="None"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_toggle"
    android:icon="@drawable/off"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

Comment: for this line `app:showAsAction="never"`  I am getting `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix`

Comment: like @Kamran said you should add this xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"